# Successful callback of $http is executing twice instead of once - Java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, http, callback

I need to generate and print checkboxes based on JSON feed for books object. So far I tried the following. There are four objects in the datalist array. In HTML, four check boxes should be created for books. But instead eight checkboxes are getting created. Any help would be much appreciated.

JSON

```
[{      
  "books" : {
    "contents" : [
        {
            "title" : "Book1",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book2",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book3",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book4",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
        }
    ]
  }
  "storybooks" : {
    "contents" : [
        {
            "title" : "Book1",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book2",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book3",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book4",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
        }
    ]
  }
}]
```

app.js

```
var datalist = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json.json'
})
    .then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.data = data.data;
        datalist = $scope.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i ++) {
            console.log(datalist[i]);
        }

        $scope.data.map(function (item) {
            item.content = item.book.contents;
            datalist = item.content;
            datalist.forEach((c, index) => {
                var btn = document.createElement('input');
                btn.type = 'checkbox';

                document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(btn);

            });
        });
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('error');
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

Comment: can you make a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvised @Try Kroll's suggestion

```
var count = 0;
http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json.json'
  })
  .then(data => {
    if(count==0){
    const myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv')
    data.data.books.contents.forEach(b => {
        const btn = document.createElement('input')
        btn.type = 'checkbox'
        perhiscontainer.appendChild(btn)
    })
  count = count+1;
}
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error', err)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were accessing the data incorrectly.

Here is a simplified version:

```
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'json.json'
      })
      .then(data => {
        const myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv')
        data.books.contents.forEach(b => {
            const btn = document.createElement('input')
            btn.type = 'checkbox'
            myDiv.appendChild(btn)
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err)
      })
```

Comment: Actually JSON has two objects namely books and storybooks. Edited the question with storybooks

Comment: Should be fine if you only use books. Edited a bit